# Loading MNIST data in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, dataset, mnist

I'm trying to download Mnist data in order to work with it futher. I need to see first 9 numbers of this dataset,  but I received an error. Here is my code:

```
install.packages("tensorflow")
library(tensorflow)
datasets <- tf$contrib$learn$datasets
mnist <- datasets$mnist$read_data_sets("MNIST-data", one_hot = TRUE)
Data = mnist$train$images[1:5000,]
Labels = mnist$train$labels[1:5000,]%*%matrix(0:9, nrow = 10)
```

Here is an error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIOS2.png)

Comment: The error is pretty clear: "Python module tensorflow was not found". Did you verify that tensorflow was correctly installed in R?

Comment: You don't have a valid python / tensorflow installation. On my machine it encourages installing `miniconda`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers how can i check this?

Comment: @Mossa miniconda has been installed

Comment: try to run it again. your screenshot clearly says that an R version is missing. If you install something on windows, you've got to restart everything to make sure all the paths, envs, etc. have been refreshed.

Comment: @Mossa i got the same error, maybe should I install Tensorflow on Windows, not only in R?

Comment: @Mossa what do you mean by last sentence in your answer with contrib?

Comment: Contrib is no longer part of `tensorflow`. The extra stuff has been removed. I've added a link to [`tfds`](https://github.com/rstudio/tfds). You should look into this

Comment: @Mossa I received the same mistake again after second launch of my code

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what to do about that. Sorry, I give up.

Comment: @Mossa thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed miniconda via `scoop`, i.e.

```
scoop install miniconda3
```

Then it recommended that I run `conda install -n root -c pscondaenvs pscondaenvs`.
First, I closed down the current `cmd`/terminal. Turned on a new one and ran

```
conda install -n root -c pscondaenvs pscondaenvs
```

Then re-ran the code you have above, and gotten an error saying `Tensorflow` module is not installed.
I then ran `conda install tensorflow` in a `cmd`/terminal.
(but it recommended to use `tensorflow::install_tensorflow()` within R, maybe try that here).

[image: Error after installing miniconda.]

Now, next is the fact that `contrib` is not part of the tensorflow module anymore.. But this is where you can get `MNIST`, using [`tfds`](https://github.com/rstudio/tfds). The installation instructions that I had to follow:

```r
remotes::install_github("rstudio/tfds")
tfds::install_tfds()
mnist <- tfds::tfds_load("mnist")
```